# Jackson printing objects even though NON_EMPTY is set

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

A part of my program turns objects into a YAML string. Below is a minimum example which produces the same results as the issue I'm running into:

**Main**

```
ObjectMapper JSONExportMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
JSONExportMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
JSONExportMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);

String export = JSONExportMapper.writeValueAsString(new Animals());
System.out.println(export);
```

**Animals**

```
class Animals {
    public Dog dog;

    public Animals() {
        this.dog = new Dog();
    }
}
```

**Dog**

```
class Dog {
    public String sound = "";
}
```

---

***The issue:***

As you can see `Dog` has the property `sound` which is an empty string. In my Jackson settings I have added `Include.NON_EMPTY` with `setSerializationInclusion`, which is supposed to prevent those properties from being included in the YAML, which it does.

Without `Include.NON_EMPTY`

```
---
dog:
  sound: ""
```

With `Include.NON_EMPTY`

```
---
dog: {}
```

---

***The question:***

Even though the object is completely empty, it still gets included in the YAML, which does not make sense to me. In my case `Animals` and `Dog` are classes from a library, which I should not change any code in.

Is there something I'm overlooking? How can I remove objects which are completely empty from the resulting YAML string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no out of the box solution so I'd suggest you should implement your own serializer

```
public class MyDogSerializer extends StdSerializer<Dog> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4796382940375974812L;

  public MyDogSerializer() {
    super(Dog.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Dog value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (/** here inspect Dog value for emptiness */) {
      gen.writeObject(null);
    } else {
      ****
    }
  }
}
```

and annotate a `dog` property

```
class Animals {
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyDogSerializer.class)
    public Dog dog;

    public Animals() {
        this.dog = new Dog();
    }
}
```